# What's difference between this.props and props from setState() updater function?

Tags: reactjs

What is the difference between these?

```
this.setState((state) => ({counter: state.counter + this.props.step}))
```

and

```
this.setState((state, props) => ({counter: state.counter + props.step}))
```

I always thought there is no difference because setState() doesn't update props, it updates only state. Maybe I don't get something.

Answer (score 1):

According to **[React](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)** Docs

this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.

**What that means ?**

let's imagine your props.step here is 1, and in the same time you execute the counter increment , another setState increment the step by 1, you will still get 1 here
like this

```
   function Parent(){
  const [step, setStep] = useState(1)
   return <>
         <button onClick={() => setStep(2)}>icrement step</button>
         <Child step={step} />
     </>
}
```

you will still get 1 here

```
this.setState((state) => ({counter: state.counter + this.props.step})) // props.step will remain 1
```

thats why you should pass props in your setState

```
this.setState((state, props) => ({counter: state.counter + props.step}))
```

Comment: **this.setState({step: 2})**
I don't understand how it should affect the props in your example. Can you expain the example in more detail?

Comment: i edited the first snippet  above